# Cannot process application with runtime: java8 : Google appEngine Deployment Error

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform

Iam trying to deploy my java8 restful api to Appengine Standard Environment.

I followed tutorial on this link : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4

Error disapperas if i use jav11 in runtime in my app.yaml
app.yaml

```
runtime: java8
instance_class: F4
```

java --version

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Error Stack Trace:

```
Detected App Engine app.yaml based application.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.283 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-22T02:03:52+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.0:deploy (default-cli) on project NC-WEBAPP: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.0:deploy failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Cannot process application with runtime: java8 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.0:deploy (default-cli) on project NC-WEBAPP: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.0:deploy failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Cannot process application with runtime: java8
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.0:deploy failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Cannot process application with runtime: java8
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Cannot process application with runtime: java8
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.stage.AppYamlStager.stage (AppYamlStager.java:59)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.AppDeployer.deploy (AppDeployer.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:55)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Cannot process application with runtime: java8
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.AppYamlProjectStaging.stageArchive (AppYamlProjectStaging.java:81)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.stage.AppYamlStager.stage (AppYamlStager.java:57)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.AppDeployer.deploy (AppDeployer.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:55)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

my GCLOUD Version:

```
Google Cloud SDK 267.0.0
app-engine-java 1.9.76
app-engine-python 1.9.86
bq 2.0.49
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2019.10.15
gsutil 4.44
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 and Java 11 on App Engine are very different in their configuration.

[With Java8](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref), you have to define a `appengine-web.xml` in the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` directory.

[With Java11](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/config/appref), it's a `app.yaml` file required in the `src/main/appengine` directory

I have a [simple github repo and the both version here](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/serverless-oracle).

By the way, your AppEngine Java11 configuration can be simply downgradé to Java8 without deep change in your configuration files. It's easier with Go, Python or Node to change of version.

If your application is compliant with Java11 (which must be the case of all Java8 application and if you don't use special App Engine libraries of Java8 version (1st generation)), use Java11.

In addition, App Engine Java11 is in GA since yesterday!

Comment: Hi Itried Deploying my project with java11 runtime with jar packaging , it only shows 500 service unavailable page. i can not find any error logs in appengine console

Comment: You should have logs in stackdriver logging part. Can you check?

Comment: Thank you, i was checking in error reporting. it was database connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

In [the tutorial](http://%20https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4) that you are trying to follow the runtime env is Java 11, as you can check in the app.yaml file.

If you want to create a Java 8 sample application on App Engine you will have some other configurations. First and most important you will need to have an appengine-web.xml in a `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` folder.

You can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart) a quickstard for an App Engine Standard application running on Java 8.

Comment: Thanks @andreiTiagu
According to docs i can only deploy a java8 project with war packaging. Iam trying to build my project around micriservices architecture with java8 api and angualr 8 forontend both as separate microservices. Any Thought on how to acheive this.

Comment: This is a totally different subject and it is related to architecture design. In order for you to get a proper answer to this I would recommend you to create a new question with this specific theme. Here you have more information about microservices architecture with Java 8 -- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/microservices-on-app-engine

Comment: OK i will create a new question about this. thank you